# Output for this test class is very confusing.Can anyone please explain the output?

Tags: java, string

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        String msg= "Hello";
        print(msg);
        msg += "world";
        print(msg);
    }

    static void print(String msg) {
        System.out.println(msg);
        msg += "tttt";
        System.out.println(msg);        
    }
}
```

OutPut:

Hello
Hellotttt
Helloworld
Helloworldtttt

Why the out has Helloworld after Hellotttt and not Hellottttworld?

Answer (score 1):

Because in method static void print(String msg) , the change in msg will only be available in this method. After the execution of print(msg) for the first time, value of msg will be "Hello" again.

If you want output like
Hello
Hellotttt
Hellottttworld
Hellottttworldtttt

you can do it like this :

```
static void main(String[] args) {   
    String msg= "Hello";
    msg = print(msg);
    msg += "world";
    print(msg);

}

static String print(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
    msg += "tttt";
    System.out.println(msg);
    return msg;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.Thanks for the reply Kamil007.